# How can we obtain location (index and column label list) for all non-numeric (both NaN and non numeric data such as string) in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

A very elegant way to obtain the index and column label list for all `NaN` values in a Pandas dataframe (when index is dates) is:

```
df.loc[pd.isnull(df).any(1), :].stack().index.tolist()
```

where `df` is primarily an int/float values dataframe with date index and string column labels.

This returns the index, column labels for all values of interest 'nan' in a list. However, I would also like to be able to capture any other value such as a random character, 'r' or 'c' that are not nan but not numeric. I have tried to look through and could not find a solution. Please help?

Comment: You should show us your `df` or the script to yield him.

Comment: please edit your question and put this script **INSIDE** the question

Comment: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` gives you a dataframe masked with `nan` where the original are not convertible to `float`.

Comment: This works!. Thank you!